# IllegalStateException: "Rejecting additional inbound receiver" using zipWith in Spring WebFlux

Tags: java, spring-webflux, reactor-netty

I try to perform two steps with the request body (`@RequestBody Flux<ByteBuffer> body`) of a WebFlux Controller method using `Mono.zipWith()`.

Unit testing the code with `WebTestClient` works as expected.

**BUT:** When the WebFlux application runs, I receive the error ("**Rejecting additional inbound receiver**") below.

The code is similar to this:

```java
    @PostMapping("/jobs")
    public Mono<ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>>> create(@RequestBody Flux<ByteBuffer> body) {

        Mono<String> mono1 = doSomethingWithTheContent(body);

        Mono<Boolean> mono2 = stopOnPatternDetection(body);

        Mono<Tuple2<String, Boolean>> zippedMono = mono1.zipWith(mono2);

        return zippedMono
            .map(Tuple2::getT1)
            .map(this::ok)
            .onErrorResume(PatternDetectedException.class, this::bad);
    }

    Mono<ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>>> bad(PatternDetectedException patternDetectedException) {
        return Mono.just(
            ResponseEntity
                .badRequest()
                .body(Map.of("detection", true))
        );
    }

    ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>> ok(String key) {
        return ResponseEntity
            .ok()
            .body(
                Map.of(
                    "key", key,
                    "detection", false
                )
            );
    }

    Mono<Boolean> stopOnPatternDetection(Flux<ByteBuffer> content) {
        return readContent(content)
            .map(bytes -> {
                if (patternIsDetected(bytes)) {
                    throw new PatternDetectedException("Pattern detected in " + Arrays.toString(bytes));
                }
                return true;
            });
    }

    Mono<String> doSomethingWithTheContent(Flux<ByteBuffer> content) {
        return readContent(content)
            .map(bytes -> new String(bytes));
    }

    Mono<byte[]> readContent(Flux<ByteBuffer> content) {

        return content
            .reduce(
                new ByteArrayOutputStream(),
                (byteArrayOutputStream, buffer) -> {
                    byteArrayOutputStream.write(buffer.array(), 0, buffer.limit());
                    return byteArrayOutputStream;
                })
            .map(ByteArrayOutputStream::toByteArray);
    }

    private boolean patternIsDetected(byte[] content) {

        return new String(content).contains("PATTERN-X");
    }
```

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Rejecting additional inbound receiver. State=[terminated=false, cancelled=false, pending=0, error=false]
    at reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive.startReceiver(FluxReceive.java:189) ~[reactor-netty-core-1.1.4.jar:1.1.4]
    Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException: 
Error has been observed at the following site(s):
    *__checkpoint ⇢ Handler com.giraone.jobs.receiver.web.rest.JobReceiveResource#create(Flux) [DispatcherHandler]
    *__checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.web.filter.reactive.ServerHttpObservationFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    *__checkpoint ⇢ HTTP POST "/api/jobs" [ExceptionHandlingWebHandler]
Original Stack Trace:
        at reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive.startReceiver(FluxReceive.java:189) ~[reactor-netty-core-1.1.4.jar:1.1.4]
        at reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive.subscribe(FluxReceive.java:148) ~[reactor-netty-core-1.1.4.jar:1.1.4]
        at reactor.core.publisher.InternalFluxOperator.subscribe(InternalFluxOperator.java:62) ~[reactor-core-3.5.3.jar:3.5.3]
        at reactor.netty.ByteBufFlux.subscribe(ByteBufFlux.java:340) ~[reactor-netty-core-1.1.4.jar:1.1.4]
        at reactor.core.publisher.InternalFluxOperator.subscribe(InternalFluxOperator.java:62) ~[reactor-core-3.5.3.jar:3.5.3]
        at reactor.netty.ByteBufFlux.subscribe(ByteBufFlux.java:340) ~[reactor-netty-core-1.1.4.jar:1.1.4]
        at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:64) ~[reactor-core-3.5.3.jar:3.5.3]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoZip$ZipCoordinator.request(MonoZip.java:216) ~[reactor-core-3.5.3.jar:3.5.3]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapConditionalSubscriber.request(FluxMap.java:295) ~[reactor-core-3.5.3.jar:3.5.3]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapConditionalSubscriber.request(FluxMap.java:295) ~[reactor-core-3.5.3.jar:3.5.3]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekTerminal$MonoTerminalPeekSubscriber.request(MonoPeekTerminal.java:139) ~[reactor-core-3.5.3.jar:3.5.3]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekTerminal$MonoTerminalPeekSubscriber.request(MonoPeekTerminal.java:139) ~[reactor-core-3.5.3.jar:3.5.3]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.set(Operators.java:2341) ~[reactor-core-3.5.3.jar:3.5.3]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxOnErrorResume.java:74) ~[reactor-core-3.5.3.jar:3.5.3]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekTerminal$MonoTerminalPeekSubscriber.onSubscribe(MonoPeekTerminal.java:152) ~[reactor-core-3.5.3.jar:3.5.3]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekTerminal$MonoTerminalPeekSubscriber.onSubscribe(MonoPeekTerminal.java:152) ~[reactor-core-3.5.3.jar:3.5.3]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapConditionalSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxMap.java:194) ~[reactor-core-3.5.3.jar:3.5.3]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapConditionalSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxMap.java:194) ~[reactor-core-3.5.3.jar:3.5.3]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoZip.subscribe(MonoZip.java:125) ~[reactor-core-3.5.3.jar:3.5.3]
        at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:64) ~[reactor-core-3.5.3.jar:3.5.3]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:165) ~[reactor-core-3.5.3.jar:3.5.3]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onNext(FluxOnErrorResume.java:79) ~[reactor-core-3.5.3.jar:3.5.3]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeek.java:200) ~[reactor-core-3.5.3.jar:3.5.3]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeek.java:200) ~[reactor-core-3.5.3.jar:3.5.3]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.complete(MonoIgnoreThen.java:292) ~[reactor-core-3.5.3.jar:3.5.3]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.onNext(MonoIgnoreThen.java:187) ~[reactor-core-3.5.3.jar:3.5.3]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:158) ~[reactor-core-3.5.3.jar:3.5.3]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoZip$ZipCoordinator.signal(MonoZip.java:293) ~[reactor-core-3.5.3.jar:3.5.3]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoZip$ZipInner.onNext(MonoZip.java:474) ~[reactor-core-3.5.3.jar:3.5.3]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekTerminal$MonoTerminalPeekSubscriber.onNext(MonoPeekTerminal.java:180) ~[reactor-core-3.5.3.jar:3.5.3]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$ScalarSubscription.request(Operators.java:2545) ~[reactor-core-3.5.3.jar:3.5.3]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekTerminal$MonoTerminalPeekSubscriber.request(MonoPeekTerminal.java:139) ~[reactor-core-3.5.3.jar:3.5.3]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoZip$ZipInner.onSubscribe(MonoZip.java:466) ~[reactor-core-3.5.3.jar:3.5.3]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekTerminal$MonoTerminalPeekSubscriber.onSubscribe(MonoPeekTerminal.java:152) ~[reactor-core-3.5.3.jar:3.5.3]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoJust.subscribe(MonoJust.java:55) ~[reactor-core-3.5.3.jar:3.5.3]
        at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:64) ~[reactor-core-3.5.3.jar:3.5.3]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoZip$ZipCoordinator.request(MonoZip.java:216) ~[reactor-core-3.5.3.jar:3.5.3]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.request(MonoFlatMap.java:194) ~[reactor-core-3.5.3.jar:3.5.3]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.onSubscribe(MonoIgnoreThen.java:134) ~[reactor-core-3.5.3.jar:3.5.3]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onSubscribe(MonoFlatMap.java:117) ~[reactor-core-3.5.3.jar:3.5.3]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoZip.subscribe(MonoZip.java:125) ~[reactor-core-3.5.3.jar:3.5.3]
        at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:64) ~[reactor-core-3.5.3.jar:3.5.3]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52) ~[reactor-core-3.5.3.jar:3.5.3]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.subscribeNext(MonoIgnoreThen.java:240) ~[reactor-core-3.5.3.jar:3.5.3]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.onComplete(MonoIgnoreThen.java:203) ~[reactor-core-3.5.3.jar:3.5.3]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onComplete(MonoFlatMap.java:189) ~[reactor-core-3.5.3.jar:3.5.3]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators.complete(Operators.java:137) ~[reactor-core-3.5.3.jar:3.5.3]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoZip.subscribe(MonoZip.java:121) ~[reactor-core-3.5.3.jar:3.5.3]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4485) ~[reactor-core-3.5.3.jar:3.5.3]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.subscribeNext(MonoIgnoreThen.java:263) ~[reactor-core-3.5.3.jar:3.5.3]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen.subscribe(MonoIgnoreThen.java:51) ~[reactor-core-3.5.3.jar:3.5.3]
        at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:64) ~[reactor-core-3.5.3.jar:3.5.3]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:165) ~[reactor-core-3.5.3.jar:3.5.3]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onNext(FluxOnErrorResume.java:79) ~[reactor-core-3.5.3.jar:3.5.3]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onNext(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:74) ~[reactor-core-3.5.3.jar:3.5.3]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.onNext(MonoNext.java:82) ~[reactor-core-3.5.3.jar:3.5.3]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMapNoPrefetch$FluxConcatMapNoPrefetchSubscriber.innerNext(FluxConcatMapNoPrefetch.java:258) ~[reactor-core-3.5.3.jar:3.5.3]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapInner.onNext(FluxConcatMap.java:863) ~[reactor-core-3.5.3.jar:3.5.3]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:129) ~[reactor-core-3.5.3.jar:3.5.3]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekTerminal$MonoTerminalPeekSubscriber.onNext(MonoPeekTerminal.java:180) ~[reactor-core-3.5.3.jar:3.5.3]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$ScalarSubscription.request(Operators.java:2545) ~[reactor-core-3.5.3.jar:3.5.3]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekTerminal$MonoTerminalPeekSubscriber.request(MonoPeekTerminal.java:139) ~[reactor-core-3.5.3.jar:3.5.3]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.request(FluxMapFuseable.java:171) ~[reactor-core-3.5.3.jar:3.5.3]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.request(Operators.java:2305) ~[reactor-core-3.5.3.jar:3.5.3]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMapNoPrefetch$FluxConcatMapNoPrefetchSubscriber.request(FluxConcatMapNoPrefetch.java:338) ~[reactor-core-3.5.3.jar:3.5.3]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.request(MonoNext.java:108) ~[reactor-core-3.5.3.jar:3.5.3]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.set(Operators.java:2341) ~[reactor-core-3.5.3.jar:3.5.3]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.onSubscribe(Operators.java:2215) ~[reactor-core-3.5.3.jar:3.5.3]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.onSubscribe(MonoNext.java:70) ~[reactor-core-3.5.3.jar:3.5.3]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMapNoPrefetch$FluxConcatMapNoPrefetchSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxConcatMapNoPrefetch.java:164) ~[reactor-core-3.5.3.jar:3.5.3]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:201) ~[reactor-core-3.5.3.jar:3.5.3]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:83) ~[reactor-core-3.5.3.jar:3.5.3]
        at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:64) ~[reactor-core-3.5.3.jar:3.5.3]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52) ~[reactor-core-3.5.3.jar:3.5.3]
        at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:64) ~[reactor-core-3.5.3.jar:3.5.3]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52) ~[reactor-core-3.5.3.jar:3.5.3]
        at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:64) ~[reactor-core-3.5.3.jar:3.5.3]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52) ~[reactor-core-3.5.3.jar:3.5.3]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4485) ~[reactor-core-3.5.3.jar:3.5.3]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.subscribeNext(MonoIgnoreThen.java:263) ~[reactor-core-3.5.3.jar:3.5.3]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen.subscribe(MonoIgnoreThen.java:51) ~[reactor-core-3.5.3.jar:3.5.3]
        at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:64) ~[reactor-core-3.5.3.jar:3.5.3]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDeferContextual.subscribe(MonoDeferContextual.java:55) ~[reactor-core-3.5.3.jar:3.5.3]
        at reactor.netty.http.server.HttpServer$HttpServerHandle.onStateChange(HttpServer.java:1006) ~[reactor-netty-http-1.1.4.jar:1.1.4]
        at reactor.netty.ReactorNetty$CompositeConnectionObserver.onStateChange(ReactorNetty.java:710) ~[reactor-netty-core-1.1.4.jar:1.1.4]
        at reactor.netty.transport.ServerTransport$ChildObserver.onStateChange(ServerTransport.java:477) ~[reactor-netty-core-1.1.4.jar:1.1.4]
        at reactor.netty.http.server.HttpServerOperations.onInboundNext(HttpServerOperations.java:633) ~[reactor-netty-http-1.1.4.jar:1.1.4]
        at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler.channelRead(ChannelOperationsHandler.java:113) ~[reactor-netty-core-1.1.4.jar:1.1.4]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:444) ~[netty-transport-4.1.89.Final.jar:4.1.89.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420) ~[netty-transport-4.1.89.Final.jar:4.1.89.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412) ~[netty-transport-4.1.89.Final.jar:4.1.89.Final]
        at reactor.netty.http.server.HttpTrafficHandler.channelRead(HttpTrafficHandler.java:228) ~[reactor-netty-http-1.1.4.jar:1.1.4]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:442) ~[netty-transport-4.1.89.Final.jar:4.1.89.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420) ~[netty-transport-4.1.89.Final.jar:4.1.89.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412) ~[netty-transport-4.1.89.Final.jar:4.1.89.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler$DelegatingChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:436) ~[netty-transport-4.1.89.Final.jar:4.1.89.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:346) ~[netty-codec-4.1.89.Final.jar:4.1.89.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:333) ~[netty-codec-4.1.89.Final.jar:4.1.89.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:454) ~[netty-codec-4.1.89.Final.jar:4.1.89.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:290) ~[netty-codec-4.1.89.Final.jar:4.1.89.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.channelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:251) ~[netty-transport-4.1.89.Final.jar:4.1.89.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:442) ~[netty-transport-4.1.89.Final.jar:4.1.89.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420) ~[netty-transport-4.1.89.Final.jar:4.1.89.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412) ~[netty-transport-4.1.89.Final.jar:4.1.89.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410) ~[netty-transport-4.1.89.Final.jar:4.1.89.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:440) ~[netty-transport-4.1.89.Final.jar:4.1.89.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420) ~[netty-transport-4.1.89.Final.jar:4.1.89.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919) ~[netty-transport-4.1.89.Final.jar:4.1.89.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:166) ~[netty-transport-4.1.89.Final.jar:4.1.89.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:788) ~[netty-transport-4.1.89.Final.jar:4.1.89.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:724) ~[netty-transport-4.1.89.Final.jar:4.1.89.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:650) ~[netty-transport-4.1.89.Final.jar:4.1.89.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:562) ~[netty-transport-4.1.89.Final.jar:4.1.89.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997) ~[netty-common-4.1.89.Final.jar:4.1.89.Final]
        at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) ~[netty-common-4.1.89.Final.jar:4.1.89.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) ~[netty-common-4.1.89.Final.jar:4.1.89.Final]
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
```